# Algorithm for the largest subarray of distinct values in linear time

Tags: algorithm, performance, time, distinct-values

I'm trying to come up with a fast algorithm for, given any array of length n, obtaining the largest subarray of distinct values.

For example, the largest subarray of distinct values of

```
[1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 8, 1, 9]
```

would be

```
[4, 2, 8, 1, 9]
```

This is my current solution, I think it runs in O(n^2). This is because check_dups runs in linear time, and it is called every time j or i increments.

```
arr = [0,...,n]
i = 0
j = 1
i_best = i
j_best = j
while i < n-1 and j < n:
    if check_dups(arr, i j): //determines if there's duplicates in the subarray i,j in linear time
        i += 1
    else:
        if j - i > j_best - i_best:
            i_best = i
            j_best = j
        j += 1
return subarray(arr, i_best, j_best)
```

Does anyone have a better solution, in linear time?

Please note this is pseudocode and I'm not looking for an answer that relies on specific existing functions of a defined language (such as arr.contains()).
Thanks!

Comment: Can you use HashSet?

Comment: @SanketMakani No, I'm writing the algorithm on my own without the use of any other objects or functions.

Comment: Unless your array values are restricted in range, no way of solving in O(n) without hashSet

Comment: "without the use of any other objects or functions" - so you're playing a puzzle rather than solving a real problem?  There is another site for that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman No. I'm trying to work my way through and understand an efficient algorithm solution at its most basic form, without the aid of existing structures that people wrote for me. Writing an algorithm with a HashSet structure and using the methods it supplies is easy and doesn't teach me anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the problem of finding the largest distinct-valued subarray *ending at a particular index `j`*. Conceptually this is straightforward: starting at `arr[j]`, you go backwards and include all elements until you find a duplicate.

Let's use this intuition to solve this problem for all `j` from `0` up to `length(arr)`. We need to know, at any point in the iteration, how far back we can go before we find a duplicate. That is, we need to know the least `i` such that `subarray(arr, i, j)` contains distinct values. (I'm assuming `subarray` treats the indices as inclusive.)

If we knew `i` at some point in the iteration (say, when `j = k`), can we quickly update `i` when `j = k+1`? Indeed, if we knew when was the last occurrence of `arr[k+1]`, then we can update `i := max(i, lastOccurrence(arr[k+1]) + 1)`. We can compute `lastOccurrence` in O(1) time with a HashMap.

Pseudocode:

```
arr = ... (from input)
map = empty HashMap
i = 0
i_best = 0
j_best = 0
for j from 0 to length(arr) - 1 inclusive:
    if map contains-key arr[j]:
        i = max(i, map[arr[j]] + 1)
    map[arr[j]] = j
    if j - i > j_best - i_best:
        i_best = i
        j_best = j
return subarray(arr, i_best, j_best)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, and yes subarray() in my pseudocode is inclusive. However, I cannot use HashMaps. I'm restricted to arrays, and everything primitive.

Comment: Why do you have this restriction? I think you're unlikely to get far without some notion of mapping keys to values. If your array contains very large numbers, then they can't be used as array indices, so they might as well be arbitrary objects. But then how are you supposed to "remember" any sort of data about arbitrary objects without mapping the objects to said data?

Comment: What's the result of applying your algorithm/pseudocode to the input, [1,2,2,2,2,2,1] ?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I just ran it and got `(i_best, j_best) = (0, 1)` as expected (first two elements inclusive)... what did you think would happen?

Comment: Ah, thanks. I think I may have misunderstood something about it.

Comment: Nice answer (HashSet not allowed notwithstanding :)

Comment: @pkpnd Yes, these restrictions aren't fully applicable to every extension of the problem. I'm just trying to write and understand an algorithm without the use of excess structures that were created for me. It's just practice for writing algorithms. Apparently O(n^2) is the fastest solution for this without using some sort of mapping.

Comment: @shplaz we can adapt pkpnd's algorithm to work in `O(n log n)` time (and potentially `O(n)`) without a hash map (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

We can adapt pkpnd's algorithm to use an array rather than hash map for an `O(n log n)` solution or potentially `O(n)` if your data allows for an `O(n)` stable sort, but you'd need to implement a stable sorting function that also provides the original indexes of the elements.

```
1 4 3 2 4 2 8 1 9
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 (indexes)
```

Sorted:

```
1 1 2 2 3 4 4 8 9
0 7 3 5 2 1 4 6 8 (indexes)
--- ---   ---
```

Now, instead of a hash map, build a new array by iterating over the sorted array and inserting the last occurrence of each element according to the duplicate index arrangements. The final array would look like:

```
 1  4  3  2  4  2  8  1  9
-1 -1 -1 -1  1  3 -1  0 -1 (previous occurrence)
```

We're now ready to run pkpnd's algorithm with a slight modification:

```
arr = ... (from input)
map = previous occurrence array
i = 0
i_best = 0
j_best = 0
for j from 0 to length(arr) - 1 inclusive:
    if map[j] >= 0:
        i = max(i, map[j] + 1)

    if j - i > j_best - i_best:
        i_best = i
        j_best = j
return subarray(arr, i_best, j_best)
```

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(arr, map){
  let i = 0
  let i_best = 0
  let j_best = 0

  for (j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
    if (map[j] >= 0)
      i = Math.max(i, map[j] + 1)

    if (j - i > j_best - i_best){
       i_best = i
       j_best = j
    }
  }

  return [i_best, j_best]
}

let arr = [ 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 8, 1, 9]
let map = [-1,-1,-1,-1, 1, 3,-1, 0,-1]
console.log(f(arr, map))

arr = [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
map = [-1,-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
console.log(f(arr, map))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use Hashtable(Dictionary in c#)

```
 public int[] FindSubarrayWithDistinctEntities(int[] arr)
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        Result r = new Result();   //struct containing start and end index for subarray
        int result = 0;
        r.st = 1;
        r.end = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {               
            if (dic.ContainsKey(arr[i]))
            {
                int diff = i - (dic[arr[i]] + 1);
                if(result<diff)
                {
                    result = diff;
                    r.st = Math.Min(r.st, (dic[arr[i]] + 1));
                    r.end = i-1;                      
                }
                dic.Remove(arr[i]);
            }
            dic.Add(arr[i], i);
        }
        return arr.Skip(r.st).Take(r.end).ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Add every number to Hashset if it isn't already in it. Hashset's insert and search are both O(1). So final result will be O(n).

Comment: Sorry, HashSet is only pseudoConstant and it is actually `O(n)` for big amount of numbers or if you are unlucky

Comment: check_dups would still need to add all values between arr[i] and arr[j] to the set.

Comment: I'm trying to come up with a solution without using any existing objects or functions that would make this easier. I want to understand a scratch implementation of this, hence the pseudocode.